# Python Plotly overlap probabilities histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I've created 3 frequencies histogram overlapped into one:

```py
df['DataA'] = .... 
df['DataB'] = .... 
df['DataC'] = .... 

barmode = 'relative'
histnorm = 'probability'

fig = px.histogram(df, x='DataA', nbins=1000, title='My Chart', barmode=barmode,histnorm=histnorm)
fig.update_xaxes(title='', showline=True, showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title='', showline=True, showgrid=False, tickformat=',.0%')

fig.add_histogram(x=df['DataB'], nbinsx=1000, histnorm=histnorm, opacity=0.7, name='Data B')
fig.add_histogram(x=df['DataC'], nbinsx=1000, histnorm=histnorm, opacity=0.7, name='Data C')

# Update layout to hide axis names
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='', yaxis_title='')

fig.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

But probability is not correct, indeed if I plot separetely each histogram I get this:
[image]
As you see the maximum probability reached by a dataseries is ~6%, while the main chart reach ~20%.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

Following Eric's suggestion I set barmode to overlay, but unfortunately still the result is far off, here's what I get in excel by manually building the frequency table:

Probability: [image: With probability]
Frequency: [image]

And here's the python result (blue is data A):
Probability: [image]
Frequency: [image]

As you see Data A should be consistently lower than Data B and C, but it's almost the same on the python plotting.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you set `barmode = 'relative'`, so the bars are *stacked* and the probabilities add up along the yaxis.

You can fix this by setting the barmode to `'overlay'` or `'group'` :

> [`barmode`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html) (str (default `'relative'`)) – One of `'group'`, `'overlay'` or
> `'relative'`.
>
> In `'relative'` mode, bars are stacked above zero for
> positive values and below zero for negative values. In `'overlay'` mode,
> bars are drawn on top of one another.  In `'group'` mode, bars are placed
> beside each other.

NB. With `barmode='overlay'` you might need to reduce the opacity to properly see all histograms (cf. [Overlaid Histogram](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#overlaid-histogram)).

Comment: I have answered to : "_the maximum probability reached by a dataseries is ~6%, while the main chart reach ~20%. Does anyone know how to fix this?_", then you unaccept the answer and edit the question, adding screenshots that are in contradiction with the initial statement "_the maximum probability reached by a dataseries is ~6%_", yet you don't provide any data+code nor bother to explain how you get those results with excel. Sorry but I can't guess.

Comment: I think there's 2 issues : the first issue was about overlaid vs stacked histogram using plotly, now you are asking why you don't get the same thing as in a picture related to excel, without providing the relevant details (which is prone to downvoting). Your 2nd issue is likely to be related to the histnorm and/or bin size, so I suggest you roll back your edits and ask a new question instead, with all the relevant details. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)